# Automatically scale Phaser 3 game dynamically mid-execution

Tags: javascript, html, css, phaser-framework

I am wondering if there is a way to develop my game with a set resolution such as:

```
width: 1000,
height: 600,
```

And then have either HTML or Phaser automatically scale the canvas element whenever the window size changes.

I have tried using this:

```
width: window.innerWidth / 2,
height: window.innerHeight / 2,
```

But this does not preserve the aspect ratio, doesn't scale sprites/images correctly, requires a page reload for adjustments and means I cannot use specific x/y coordinates.

I have looked into Phaser 3's Scale manager and Flex Boxes but they do not seem to change the canvas size.

Comment: can you generate a dummy and working fiddle for it?

Comment: How did you attempt to use ScaleManager? It's supposed to resize the canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution that I could find was the following:

- **First**, add these CSS styling rules:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #111;
  color: #eee;
  font: caption;
}

canvas {
  /* And see postBoot() in JS */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  /* <https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit> */
}

#version {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 605px;
}
```

- **Second**, add a callback function in the `config` object to override Phaser's default styles like so:

```
var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 200 }
    }
  },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
  },
  callbacks: {
    postBoot: function (game) {
      // In v3.15, you have to override Phaser's default styles
      game.canvas.style.width = '100%';
      game.canvas.style.height = '100%';
    }
  }
};
```

I found the code sample **[here](https://codepen.io/samme/pen/paOjMO)**.

**EDIT**:

If you want the game to resize whenever the window is changed mid-execution, you can make a similar function in your update loop like so:

```
function update(){
    (function() {
        const gameId = document.getElementById("game"); // Target div that wraps the phaser game
        gameId.style.width = '100%'; // set width to 100%
        gameId.style.height = '100%'; // set height to 100%
    })(); // run function
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, this is very close to what I was looking for. I made a slight modification by adding your function to my update loop. This way it resizes whenever the window is changed, even during execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

It allowes you to adjust you css to a viewport.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that then all my sprites will not be scaled, only the canvas. I'm looking for something that will scale the entire game depending on screen size (like a flex box), that doesn't change Phaser's interpretation of what is width and height of the game are.

Comment: can you add this to your html head and see what it does?
<meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

Comment: On page load the screen is at it's normal size. When I shrink the page it continues to be at normal size. Expanding the image now causes it to swallow the entire page width.

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything that could help you

Comment: No problem, Thanks for trying